# Rails 4.1: NameError in Jobs#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Want to show different job categories for my jobs board , using the simple form gem  I have added the following to my jobs form.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@job, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>

<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a category" }, input_html: { class: "dropdown-toggle" } %>


    <%= f.input :title, label: "Job Title", input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
    <%= f.input :description, label: "Job Description", input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
    <%= f.input :company, label: "Your Company", input_html: {class: "form-control" } %>
    <%= f.input :url, label: "Link to Job", input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
    <br/>
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

but when i go to jobs.new.html it generates the following error

NameError in Jobs#new
Showing /Users/neilpatel/Desktop/Rails/jobs_board/app/views/jobs/_form.html.erb where line #3 raised:
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Category

```
<%= simple_form_for(@job, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>

  **<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a category" }, input_html: { class: "dropdown-toggle" } %>** -<error


    <%= f.input :title, label: "Job Title", input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error specifies you don't have `Category` Model in your application. That's why rails considering `Category` as constant and throwing this error `uninitialized constant`. Try add `Category` Model in you `app/models` directory.

`<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a category" }, input_html: { class: "dropdown-toggle" } %>`

`Category.all` Should be `Modelname.all`